# Getting divs to play together

Tags: html

What I want to do:

[image: img]
The img always staying to the left and that red content never moving to the left of the image

The code:

```css
#content{
border: solid #d8d9da 1px;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
background-color:#ffffff;
border-radius: 4px;
margin:5%;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

.main_row{
background-color: PURPLE ;
height:auto;
min-height:50px;
margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}

.row_content{
background-color: RED ;
height:auto;
min-height:50px;
background-color:red;
word-wrap: break-word;
display:inline-block;
float:right;
}

.thumbnail{
background-color: GREEN ;
height:50px;
width:100px;
}

.row_extra{
font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="content">

  <div class="main_row">

   <div class="thumbnail">IMG</div>
   <div class="row_content">
    Reflection makeReflection makeReflection makeReflection makeReflection makeReflection make Reflection makeReflection makeReflection make
    <div class="row_extra">extra stuffhere</div>
   </div>
  
  </div>
 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added `display:table` to the parent div and `table-cell` to childs instead of inline-block.

Now IMG will stay always left and content in red wont never move to left

```
.main_row{
background-color: PURPLE ;
height:auto;
min-height:50px;
margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
display:table;
float:left;
}

.row_content{
background-color: RED ;
height:auto;
min-height:50px;
background-color:red;
word-wrap: break-word;
float:right;
  display:table-cell;
}

.thumbnail{
background-color: GREEN ;
height:50px;
width:100px;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/pimotisoxi/3/edit

Comment: That's interesting I wasn't really even aware of the idea of adding 'table attributes' without actually using tables. Are there any downsides to them that you know of? They seem really useful

Comment: @DardanM, by adding table properties to divs doesn't cause any issue, Infact by adding table-cell property your can decrease layout code. More you can read here.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Comment: You can always check CanIuse to see if it has good browser support. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to skin a cat, but you should not use both inline-blocks and floats. Floating an inline-block defeats the purpose of having a block in a *inline* text-context. If you want to align a inline-block you should use `text-align:left` on the parent container instead.

Here is one approach (not using inline-blocks).

```css
#content{
border: solid #d8d9da 1px;
/* display:inline-block; */
/* float:left; */
/* Defaults to normal block taking up 100% width */
background-color:#ffffff;
border-radius: 4px;
margin:5%;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

.main_row{
background-color: PURPLE ;
height:auto;
min-height:50px;
margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
/* display:inline-block; */
float:left; 
}

.row_content{
background-color: RED ;
height:auto;
min-height:50px;
background-color:red;
word-wrap: break-word;
/* display:inline-block; */
/* float:right; */ 
/* Defaults to a normal block taking up 100% width */
margin-left: 100px; /* Add left-margin (visible below the thumbnail. */
}

.thumbnail{
background-color: GREEN ;
height:50px;
width:100px;
float:left;
}

.row_extra{
font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="content">

  <div class="main_row">

   <div class="thumbnail">IMG</div>
   <div class="row_content">
    Reflection makeReflection makeReflection makeReflection makeReflection makeReflection make Reflection makeReflection makeReflection make
    <div class="row_extra">extra stuffhere</div>
   </div>
  
  </div>
 
 </div>
```

Comment: This looks good, only thing is to get content class to change height based on content height. I tried messing with setting height:auto and min-height but couldn't get it to budge. Damn clicked enter for space but it entered comment - I was also going to write that - yeah initially I only had inline-block but added floats trying to get it to work with that instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this float both the thumbnail & row_content class to left. add the code below to the bottom of your css

```
.thumbnail, .row_content {
      float: left;
}
```